# How do I obtain regression results from a 2-way ANCOVA with a random effect (linear mixed model) in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, ancova

My dataset includes the following variables:

- Response variable - respiration rate (continuous)
- Regression variable/covariate - weight (continuous)
- Explanatory variables - temperature (2 levels: high and low) and pH (2 levels: high and low), fully crossed
- Block - date (4 days)

Here is the mixed model that I initially set up with the summary results:

```
model3 <- lmer(resp.rate ~ temp*pH + weight + (1|date), data = msblue)
> summary(model3)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: resp.rate ~ temp * pH + weight + (1 | date)
   Data: msblue

REML criterion at convergence: 428.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.54411 -0.62765  0.01564  0.45268  1.86199 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 date     (Intercept) 735479   857.6   
 Residual             161785   402.2   
Number of obs: 32, groups:  date, 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3792.34     584.49    8.98   6.488 0.000114 ***
temp1        -177.93      71.73   24.00  -2.480 0.020530 *  
pH1           -14.40      71.88   24.00  -0.200 0.842867    
weight       -485.43      91.39   24.20  -5.312 1.84e-05 ***
temp1:pH1     -22.36      71.13   23.99  -0.314 0.756013    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr) temp1  pH1    weight
temp1      0.088                     
pH1        0.098  0.019              
weight    -0.669 -0.132 -0.146       
temp1:pH1 -0.017 -0.003 -0.004  0.026
```

My questions are the following:

1. Did I set up my model correctly based on the variables of interest?
2. How do I interpret these results as a regression of weight and respiration rate for each level of temperature and pH? I.e. how do I compare the relationship of weight and respiration rate between each temperature and pH treatments?
3. I am not sure if I should use the summary() function or something else. Would including random slopes in the model help with obtaining the regression results I'm looking for?

Comment: This is probably a question about software.  It sounds like you want to use the *anova* function in the *lmerTest* package to obtain results akin to an anova table.  For individual comparisons, you probably want to use the *emmeans* package.

Comment: I won't comment on the model except to note that some people will tell you it's not useful to treat Date as a random effect as it has only 4 levels.  Others will say it does no harm to include it as a random effect, though it could also be modeled as a fixed effect.